# IDEA Javascript Chrome Remote Debugging

Tags: google-chrome, intellij-idea

I try to get the JetBrains IDE Support 2.0.9 running with my IDEA 2017.1.4.
IDEA says that it waits for connection from the Support Extension on IDE port 63342.
The problem I found is that the Chrome Plugin gets an 404 error when it tries to create the WebSocket Connection

```
Ready to load system latest for IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.4 (127.0.0.1:63342)
logging.kt:43 System latest loaded for IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.4 (127.0.0.1:63342)
socket.kt:50 WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:63342/jsonRpc?v=2.0.9&f=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%206.1%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F59.0.3071.115%20Safari%2F537.36' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
value @ socket.kt:50
value @ socket.kt:69
value @ platform.kt:32
value @ chrome.kt:23
$f9 @ console.kt:57
$fb @ bootstrap.kt:157
$fc @ bootstrap.kt:174
logging.kt:51 onerror [object Event]
value @ logging.kt:51
$f4 @ socket.kt:92
```

I try to find some solution via Google but the keyword "jsonRpc" polluted the results with no connections to IDEA that helped.

Further informations:

- Network has no access to Internet
- Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115 64-Bit
- OS: Win 7 64bit
- IDEA 2017.1.4
- Plugin 2.0.9

Installed IDEA Plugins (External Ones)

- Atlassian Connector for IntelliJ IDE (Version 3.0.16,SVN:1504201227)
- CodeReview for IntelliJ IDEA (Version 0.5.4)
- Grep Console (Version 5.9.141.000)
- IDETalk (Version 145.258.11)
- Lombok Plugin (Version 0.14.16)
- SonarLint (Version 2.3.2)
- String Manipulatio (Version 4.2.132.445)
- Maven Helper (Version 3.1.138.1503)

I know that some could be very old but we don't have Internet Access at our Workstation to se updates or even update very good
PS: is there some kind of documentation what all the WebInterface URLs in IDEA are/how the Interface is constructed?

Comment: this is the first time that I hear of such issue. Do you have a network proxy set up proxy? can the port be blocked by a firewall?

Comment: No Proxy and the Only firewall settings are for outgoing traffic (not localhost traffic)